# How can I modify a created IAM Role's assume-role policy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

My objective is to be able to set up an IAM Role which can assume a role of a certain IAM user. After the creation of the role, I would like to come back later and modify this role by adding external IDs to establish a trust relationship. Let me illustrate with an example:

Let's say I want to create role:

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "happy_role" {
  name               = "happy-role"
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.happy_assume_rule_policy.json
}
```

Let's also assume that `happy_assume_role_policy` looks something like:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "happy_assume_role_policy" {
  statement {
    effect  = "Allow"
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]
    principals {
      type        = "AWS"
      identifiers = [var.some_iam_user_arn]
    }
  }
}
```

Now, I will use the created role to create an external integration. But once I am done creating that integration, I want to go back to the role I originally created and modify it's assumed role policy. So now I want to add a condition to the assume role policy and make it look like:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "happy_assume_role_policy" {
  statement {
    effect  = "Allow"
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]
    principals {
      type        = "AWS"
      identifiers = [var.snowflake_iam_user_arn]
    }
    condition {
      test     = "StringEquals"
      values   = [some_integration.integration.external_id]
      variable = "sts:ExternalId"
    }
  }
}
```

In other words, my workflow should be like:

1. Create role without assume conditions
2. Create an integration with that role
3. Take the ID from the created integration and go back to the created role and add a condition on it

Edit:
By "integration" I mean something like [this](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/chanzuckerberg/snowflake/latest/docs/resources/storage_integration). Once an Integration is created, there is an outputted ID, and then I need to take that ID and feed it back to the Assume Role I originally created. That should happen everytime I add a new integration.

Comment: Can you clarify what do you mean by "integration with that role"? Do you have an example of such an "integration"?

Comment: @Marcin I am trying to setup that for Snowflake DB. The storage integration looks like: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/chanzuckerberg/snowflake/latest/docs/resources/storage_integration   and the description here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-s3-config-storage-integration.html#step-1-configure-access-permissions-for-the-s3-bucket

Comment: The External ID does not get created until an Integration is created. So I need to take back that External ID and modify the IAM role with conditions (everytime I add a new integration)

Comment: I see. It seems like some kind of circular dependency. Sadly, I'm not to familiar with snowflake, thus can't help much. But hopefully the extra clarifications will enable someone else to solve the issue.

Comment: @Marcin No worries! The clarifications were very helpful. I basically want to replace an assume role policy with an existing one while making sure that happens in the correct order (I don't know if that's feasible)

Comment: Solution might be to have two IAM roles - one will create integration and it will also create another IAM role, that integration can assume

Comment: @rkm I would probably then need to remove the meta role once I am done. Is there a way to create a role and remove it within the same tf module?

Comment: The documented process of temporarily entering a "dummy ID such as `0000`" is a pretty awkward and unusual design for an AWS service, and unfortunately I don't think it will be possible to replicate it in Terraform. It may be best to send some feedback to AWS about the system design here, to ask for some way to do this that doesn't require creating a fake policy and then returning to edit it later, because even outside of Terraform that's a pretty bizarre workflow.  The more typical design for other AWS services is to grant the service itself access to assume the role.

Answer (score 1):

I first tried to create two IAM roles, one for managing the integration creation, and another for managing the integration itself. That ran without circular reference errors; however, I was not able to establish a connection from the storage to the database, as it needs to be the same IAM Role creating and managing the integration.

This is what I have ended up doing (still not good for an accepted way to do it IMO). I created a role (with targeting) like:

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "happy_role" {
  name               = "happy-role"
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.basic_policy.json
}
```

And used a basic assume role policy (without conditions). And then for the next run, I applied (without targeting) and it worked.

Comment: Would you mind expanding a bit on this "workaround"? Or provide an example of the terraform plan commands you used for each "run" (I'm assuming by "targeting" you mean the -target option in the plan command)? I'm having the exact same issue with an Snowflake integration and not quite understanding the solution you arrived at.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the approach mentioned here, [How to create a Snowflake Storage Integration with AWS S3 with Terraform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68311357/how-to-create-a-snowflake-storage-integration-with-aws-s3-with-terraform)

As part of Storage Integration creation, just provide the role arn which is manually constructed without the resource is created. Terraform wont complain.  Then create the role with the assume policy referring to the External Id and User ARN created by the Storage Integration