# How to create a Snowflake Storage Integration with AWS S3 with Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, amazon-iam

I am trying to use Terraform to set up a Snowflake "Storage Integration" object that links to an AWS S3 bucket. I'm using the "chanzuckerberg" Snowflake provider from the Terraform registry in addition to the standard AWS provider.

The issue I have is that part of the process to create the integration requires the following sequence of actions:

1. Create an [IAM Role](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/iam_role) with S3 access policy
2. Create a Snowflake [Storage Integration](https://github.com/chanzuckerberg/terraform-provider-snowflake/blob/main/docs/resources/storage_integration.md) object, specifying the IAM Role created in step 1
3. Modify the IAM Role access policy using values from the Storage Integration object

(complete list of steps [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-s3-config-storage-integration.html))

Hence there is a circular dependency between the IAM Role and Storage Integration. Steps 1 and 2 are straightforward but I'm not sure how to implement step 3 with Terraform as in involves modifying an object's state after it has been created.

Unfortunately it looks like the IAM Role access policy cannot be modified separate from the role itself.

Is such a thing possible or does the circular relationship between the resources mean this can't be handled by Terraform?

Comment: The AWS API would need to be updated to differentiate endpoints for the IAM Role versus its associated access policy. Otherwise yes: you have a circular dependency in your use case.

Comment: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/27188

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Terraform dependency cycles with IAM roles have a straightforward workaround. The role ARN can be precalculated, and the integration resource then has no dependency on the role. The role can then use the integration outputs freely.

Sample code:

```
locals {
  role_name = "my_role"
  role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:role/${local.role_name}"
}

resource "snowflake_storage_integration" "int" {
  storage_aws_role_arn = local.role_arn
  ...
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "role" {
  name = local.role_name
  assume_role_policy = jsonencode({
    "Version" : "2012-10-17"
    "Statement" : [
      {
        "Action" : "sts:AssumeRole"
        "Effect" : "Allow"
        "Principal" : {
          "AWS" : snowflake_storage_integration.int.storage_aws_iam_user_arn
        }
        "Condition" : {
          "StringEquals" : {
            "sts:ExternalId" : snowflake_storage_integration.int.storage_aws_external_id
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  })
}
```

Comment: This is pretty similar to what we ended up doing to break the circular dependency, i.e. calculating the role arn instead of reading it from terraform state. It's not ideal as there a small chance that the arn structure might change (this has happened on a few occasions with AWS) and therefore break the code but we decided the risk was low enough and it was really the only work around available.

Answer (score 2):

This module already helps make it a turn-key deployment.

https://github.com/Snowflake-Labs/terraform-snowflake-storage-integration

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: We also talk about the issue faced and resolutions in this blog post :) https://medium.com/snowflake/generic-external-function-framework-9aa1d20706fb Hope you find it useful.

Comment: Basically does the same as what Jarl suggested, by building the role arn from the account id and role name rather than using the output of the iam role creation. This didn't exist when I was trying to put a module together but it's nice to get some validation that we went with the right approach!